# Sum value based on drop down list and date ranges

Tags: google-sheets

My goal is to be able to see the [`SUM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) of column H (Tithe/Dollar amount) based on which month I choose via a drop down tab from data validation in I2.

So for instance: I2 is my selectable data validation cell with my months pulled in from another sheet (Jan, Feb, Mar, etc). I3 is the cell I would like the output of the sum (Column H) to. When I select August in I2, I want the formula to pull all dates from August in my B column, and then SUM column H (corresponding dollar amounts) based on those August dates to cell I3. Likewise for Sept, Oct, etc.

This way each time I select a different month from the drop down list in cell I2, I'm seeing Tithe data from only the month selected. I hope this explains what I'm trying to accomplish. If it's not clear enough let me know and I'll try to explain it a different way or more in depth as I can. I've tried a couple different ways and nothing has worked dynamically. For instance:

```
=sumproduct(MONTH(B4:B) = 8,H4:H)
```

works great to show me the total amount I need for August. But it doesn't incorporate the dropdown so I can't select September and have it do the same for September dates. I'm trying not to hard code everything so that I have to continually keep adding additional criteria manually.

Here's the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17EynQNWsdqA0lI7Pmn5lu84C41iggXr7yV1oDKqVtpI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do either a [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) or [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) on the name of the month to get the number of the month, then you can compare it with the number of the month in column B:

```
=sumproduct(month(B4:B)=match(I2,Months!B1:B12,0),H4:H)
```

[image]

Comment: Having looked at @anonymous's answer, I can now see that =sumproduct(text(B4:B,"mmmm")=I2,H4:H)  would have been shorter :-)

Comment: Yes! thank you. That's been driving me nuts. I marked your answer and tried up voting but I'm not high enough to change anything on stacked yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(MONTH(B4:B12),MATCH(I2, TEXT(DATE(2017, ROW(1:12),1),"mmmm"),0),H4:H12))
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, this would definitely work except for the only issue of going into 2018. But would be fine until then.

Comment: You could try `SUMIFS` to make a similar conditions - YEAR criterion and MONTH criterion.

Comment: Also,Quoting @Tom Sharpe's answer, ` =sumproduct(text(B4:B,"mmmm")=I2,H4:H,text(B4:B,"yyyy")=J2) ` where J2(like I2) will be the drop down year, You'll be looking for.

Comment: BTW  =sumif(text(B4:B,"MMMM"),I2,H4:H)  also works if entered as an array formula